# PHP detect Windows or Unix format of csv or txt file?

Tags: php, sql, csv

I am using PHP to upload a file to the server and then I pass the path to a SQL stored procedure that does a `BULK INSERT` to import the file into a SQL table.

In SQL I know how to get BULK INSERT to work with both Windows and Unix based csv and txt files but I need to know which format it is.

I was hoping that I could figure this out in PHP and then just pass it to the stored procedure. Then I can update the `ROWTERMINATOR` accordingly.

Is there a way in PHP to detect if a csv or txt is Windows or Unix based?

Any help with this would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Read a few lines using fgets() and test for "\r\n" or for "\n" as the last characters in the string - pay particular heed to http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the first line from file. Check if the last two chars or the last char are:

- `\r\n` -> windows
- `\n`   -> unix

Example:

```
$lines = file('test.csv');
$line = $lines[0];

switch(TRUE) {
    case substr($line, -2) === "\r\n" :
        echo "windows";
        break;
    case substr($line, -1) === "\n" :
        echo "unix";
        break;
    default :
        // pigs can fly
        echo "unknown line ending"
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! :) I like this usage too. Note that with this usage you are enabled to have *strict* comparison with `switch`. A regular swich would work like using `==` operator

Comment: Yep +1 for the case usage!